# Vlookup style csv merge using batch file

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a small batch file that merges two csv files based on matching values. See below code:

```
@ECHO OFF 
for /f "tokens=1 delims=, skip=1" %%i in (File2.csv) do @findstr  "%%i," File1.csv >nul & If     errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 (for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%m in ('findstr /i /L "%%i," File1.csv') do (@echo %%1,%%2,%%3,%%4>>output.csv 
echo %%i))
```

My file2.csv contains 4 columns of data, and my file1.csv contains 2 columns of data. Column 1 on both and is the unique value that I want to match (it is a filename including the extension).

I want my output csv to contain all 4 columns of data from File2.csv, plus column 2 of File1.csv that it has been matched against.

I would then like the first column of the output csv to be removed and replaced with this additional column 2 from File1.csv.

I hope I have explained this well enough, and I would just like to know if this is possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What type of data? It is helpful to show an example of your desired output. To clarify, match on column 1 of each file and output all columns from file2 + column 2 from file1?

Comment: Is there a way I can upload sample files that would be easier?

Comment: No upload function native with StackOverflow, but **[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)** and **[gist](https://gist.github.com/)** are popular.  Otherwise you have to copy paste into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Code modified as response to the comments*

**EDIT 2**: *Quotes in File1.csv removed*

The Batch file below assume the following:

**File1.csv:**

```
"file name.ext","col1-2"
```

**File2.csv:**

```
file name.ext,col2-2,col2-3,col2-4
```

**Output.csv:**

```
col1-2,col2-2,col2-3,col2-4
```

.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load File1 as lookup table:
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (File1.csv) do (
   set "filename=%%~a"
   set "col1_2[!filename: =_!]=%%~b"
)

rem Process File2:
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (File2.csv) do (
   set "filename=%%a"
   for /F %%f in ("!filename: =_!") do if defined col1_2[%%f] (
      echo !col1_2[%%f]!,%%b
   ) else (
      echo NoMatchingFilename,%%b
   )
)
```

Comment: The assumption was near enough spot on, only I don't need column 1-2 on the end of the output aswel, I just need it to replace the filename in column a. Also my data does not contain headers, not sure if this will affect it?

Comment: Please clear this point: does not File1.csv nor File2.csv contain headers? Then, what the `skip=1` in the `for` command in your code is used for?

Comment: That is correct none contain headers and this code was compiled through copying and pasting bits of code together. I am not experienced in this area and therefore don't fully understand the code myself. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thank you, this produces the exact format I want, however it doesn't seem to match the files. There are matching values on both csv's but on my output in column 1 I just have NoMatchingFilename

Comment: please ignore my last comment, it wasn't matching because my file1.csv contained " around the data. Thanks.

Comment: Further to this, is there a way that I can have the batch file remove " from file1.csv?

Comment: Please, confirm this: is the data in File1.csv like: `"file name.ext",col1-2`? or like `"file name.ext","col1-2"`? In the last case, do you want the quotes in `"col1-2"`? Is the data in File2.csv the same?

Comment: The data in file1.csv is like "file name.ext","col1-2". file2.csv doesn't contain the " as this is generated in a different way, hence why it didn't match. I guess I only need the " removing from the filename however it wouldn't harm to remove all of them if possible. Many thanks